# How to check for an attribute in a variable-selector using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I'm having the following Jquery code:

```
$('div:jqmData(wrapper="true"):jqmData(ex="true") div:jqmData(role="page")').each(function(index) { 
     // do sth 
     });
```

I want to replace *$('div:jqmData(wrapper="true")* with my variable *page*.

**Question:**
How do I get the above syntax working with my variable *page*? This is not really working:

```
page.is(':jqmData(ex="true")').find('div:jqmData(role="page")').each(function() { 
   // do sth 
   });
```

Thanks for some inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.is` returns a boolean indicating whether the selector applies to one ore more elements in the set. To filter the current set, use `.filter` instead:

```
page.filter(':jqmData(ex="true")').find(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The is function in jquery only return true of false, so you can use it in an if statement like below:

```
if(page.is(':jqmData(ex="true")'))
{
    page.find('div:jqmData(role="page")').each(function() { 
        // do sth
    });
}
```